# Can't use appendChild with Mustache rendered template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a simple [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) template:

```
var template = '<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: red;">TEST</div>';

var rendered = Mustache.render(template);
```

I want to add this to the body with `appendChild`:

```
document.body.appendChild(rendered);
```

But this produces the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mustache.render(template);` returns a `String` of html and you try to pass it to `appendChild` that expects a `Node`. Possible solution:

```
var template = '<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background: red;">TEST</div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', Mustache.render(template));
```